# Explicit specialization has already been instantiated

Tags: c++

I would like to put the implementation of the specializations of a templated function to a separate source file, but if I try to call it (in MyAction), I get this error:

```
Explicit specialization has already been instantiated
```

I have no idea, why I get this error.
Example code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, " << XX::MyClass().MyMethod<1>() << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

**MyClass.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

namespace XX {

    struct MyClass {

        std::string MyAction() {
            return MyMethod<0>() + MyMethod<1>();
        }

        template<int>
        std::string MyMethod();

    };

    template<>
    std::string MyClass::MyMethod<0>();

    template<>
    std::string MyClass::MyMethod<1>();

}
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

namespace XX {

    template<>
    std::string MyClass::MyMethod<0>() {
        return "FOO";
    }

    template<>
    std::string MyClass::MyMethod<1>() {
        return "BAR";
    }

}
```

Is there a template instantiation rule, which I am not aware of?

Comment: VisualStudio 2017

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/ZmpFCR

Comment: I don't think you can put template functions in a cpp-file and call them from another translation unit. As far as I know, template functions need to either be in a header file or directly in the cpp-file where they're called.

Comment: @rashmatash not necessarily. If you list every instanciation that will be used, there is nothing preventing you to put your templates in a CPP. However, this is not always possible.

Comment: Yes he can. There must be at least on translation unit which defines specific instrumentation of template and other translation units can use it without seeing definition.

Comment: I recall having seen a similar issue around here (also with MSVC) which was fixed by doing something like `template<> extern std::string MyClass::MyMethod<1>();`. But I'm not sure if it was this exact problem.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271119/explicit-instantiation-of-function-template-specialization, your code is correct btw. It's likely an MSVC problem/bug.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I've provided a godbolt link, gcc fails too. I checked also a clang and it fails. In link you have provided there is no usage of template before specialization was defined.

Comment: @MarekR Oh, you're totally right. My bad!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok looks like problem is an order.

When you are defining `MyAction` compiler tries instantiate template, but he doesn't know about specialization.

When you declare `MyAction` and define it in cpp after template specialization it will work.

```cpp
// header part
#include <string>

namespace XX {
    struct MyClass {
        template<int>
        std::string MyMethod();
        std::string MyAction();
    };
}

// cpp part
namespace XX {
    template<>
    std::string MyClass::MyMethod<0>() {
        return "a";
    }

    template<>
    std::string MyClass::MyMethod<1>() {
        return "b";
    }

    std::string MyClass::MyAction() {
        return MyMethod<0>() + MyMethod<1>();
    }
}
```

See here: https://godbolt.org/z/aGSB21

Note if you move `MyClass::MyAction()` above `MyClass::MyMethod<1>()` error will come back.

Here is version where specialization is can be declared in header file: https://godbolt.org/z/kHjlne